# searching users in active directory c# ldap

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, ldap-query

I am trying to get users who are members of a particular group in AD.

I am trying with the following filters but i am unsuccessful.

1)

```
DirectoryEntry entry1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=xxinfo,DC=com");
string query = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=Guests))";
```

2)

```
objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=Network Configuration perators,CN=Builtin,DC=xxxx,DC=xxinfo,DC=com))";
```

also, is there any way to get users using this approach?

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "group_name");
```

this searches the current domain, i want to search the whole forest.is there any way to initialize ctx for whole forest?

any help would be appreciated.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer!!
used below code
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,                            "subdomain.domain.comany.com:3268", "DC=comapny,DC=com"))
                {
                    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,   "Group_Name");

port 3268 is used to search in global catalog.